# SharedPreferences how to add message programmatically or how to add text programmatically on display

Tags: android

In SharedPReferences I have some ListPreference with the array of values.

Example:

```
<ListPreference
            android:entries="@array/list_of_languages"
            android:entryValues="@array/list_of_languages_values"
            android:key="list_of_languages"
            android:summary="@string/desc_language_specified"
            android:title="@string/title_language_specified"
            android:defaultValue="en_US" />
```

if i choose language "China" which is not supported can I write some message to display that this language is not supported? Or even better add text to SharedPreference preference.xml file?

Comment: You mean having a spinner or something in the UI?

Comment: something like this or new textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always register a [preference change listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setOnPreferenceChangeListener%28android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener%29) for `ListPreference` and in the callback you could set it back to default if it is not supported.

Comment: thank you. Can i also store this permament into pereference? Until next chnage of list_of_languages?

Comment: You can use the key "list_of_languages" to change teh preference